# How to rotate texture

Tags: mesh

I am making a rim that should look like it is made of aluminum (CNC turned).
How can I rotate the texture in such a way that it looks like it was actually turned CNC?
In the direction of the red circle with the arrows.
[image]

Comment: Hello :). In this case it's a good idea to use a UV map. Then you'll have the best cotrol.

Comment: You can try to change the scaling or rotation on different axis within your mapping node. But your rim has a bit more complex geometry, so I recommend uv unwrapping it and using UV texture coordinate instead of the generated coordinate. EDIT: [tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBUfMKKZDo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all for the answers, I solved it like "aphatetic_artist" they, (see photo). [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your object is rotated, but instead of setting *Scale X* to 200 in the *Mapping Node*, try *Scale Z* with 200 and X and Y at 1 (or maybe only 0.5) and change the *Texture Coordinate* from *Generated* to *Object*. If Z isn't correct axis, try setting Y to 200.

And if you're going to color your object, you don't need that *Mix RGB* node, because you're just flipping black to white and vice versa. But since the *Noise Texture* generates an even distribution of the 0 to 1 range, flipping the colors doesn't make much of a difference.

On the other hand, the *Height* input of the *Bump* node converts greyscale values to height information - so it's best to use the *Fac* output of the *Noise Texture* instead of *Color*.